# Forward remote address to local, DNAT just stuck

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

The server has an ip address `192.168.154.200`, when I connect to port 80, I would like this to be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:8000`, similar to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000` of nginx.

So I tried the following,

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.154.200 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

It does not work at all, when I do `curl 192.168.154.200` on the client, it stuck, what did I miss?

P.S `curl 127.0.0.1:8000` works on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.route_localnet=1
```

or

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

You may need to double check to ensure kernel supports `route_localnet`. Replace eth1 appropriately.

Please note that this `route_localnet` is off for security reasons.